# Must be declared?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOP
BEFORE DELETE ON VILLE
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
IF DELETING THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,"immposible de supprimer");
END IF;
END;
/
```

Hi,I want to create trigger that refuses to delete a city but i get this error:
'immposible de supprimer' must be declared

Comment: Use single quotes for your string, instead of double quotes

Comment: If you plan on refusing to delete EVERY city  like in your example, it would be more appropriate to give different roles to your users, and giving appropriate grants / deny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, some text between `"` [denotes an identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm.), the name of a table or a field for example.

You should use `'`, which denotes a `string` literal:

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'immposible de supprimer');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have surrounded a text string with double quotes.  Oracle thinks you are referring to a database object.  Change the double quotes to single quotes.